# Phalcon routes in js files

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony, phalcon

I want to use phalcon's dynamic routing in the js files.

For example, I have angular js code in the js files and I need to populate a list of objects that I get from a controller action *listAction* (/users/list) or I need to push changes to an object that is a controller action *saveAction* (/user/save).

I do not like hardcoding the routes in the js files like

```
$http.get("http://localhost/sample/users/list").success(function(response){
//my code here
});
```

I would like to use phalcon's router in the js files like the following:

```
$http.get("{{ url('users/list')").success(function(response){
//my code here
});
```

Right now I'm separating the javascript from the controller action's view by creating a partial .volt file and putting all the javascript related to that view in there.

Is there a better way? Is there a way I can have access to the phalcon router in js files? I use **FOSJsRoutingBundle** in Symfony is there an alternative for phalcon?

Answer (score 1):

this is an example.
put block in Your layout.volt:

```
<html>
<head>
  {% include 'js.volt' %}
  {% block js %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <script>
      {% block include_js %}{% endblock %}
    </script>

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

js.volt:

```
<script src="path/to/js/file.js"></script>
```

and in Your view (users/list.volt) do:

```
{% extends 'layout.volt' %}

{% block js %}
   <script src="path/to/js/another/js/file.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block include_js %}
  $http.get("{{ url('users/list')").success(function(response){
    //my code here
  });
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
BLABLABLA
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Still I cannot use the router in the js file. Your code above is a good structure for the view but I want to be able to do $http.get & $http.post in the javascript files and use the router right in there as there are lots of places in the js file that I require the router.

Comment: This is how with the FOSJsRoutingBundle you can give a route to the $.get right in the javascript file:
`$.get(Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10, foo: "bar" }));`